# Multiple expectations causes crash on waitForExpectationsWithTimeout

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, asynchronous, xctestexpectation

Here are the asynchronous functions I'm testing in Xcode using XCTestExpectation.

```
-(void)syncData:(void (^)(NSString *type, NSError *error))completionBlock {
[self fetchAWithCompletionBlock:^ {
    completionBlock(@"a",nil);
}];

[self fetchBWithCompletionBlock:^ {
    completionBlock(@"b",nil);
}];

[self fetchCWithCompletionBlock:^ {
    completionBlock(@"c",nil);
}];
}
```

To test the code I created 3 expectations to wait for each of the asynchronous calls to complete.

```
[appDelegate syncData:^(NSString *type, NSError *error) {
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
        [expectation1 fulfill];
    }
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"b"]) {
        [expectation2 fulfill];
    }
    if ([type isEqualToString:@"c"]) {
        [expectation3 fulfill];
    }
}];
```

When I wait for the expectations to fulfill using the default

```
[self waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:60 handler:^(NSError *error) {}
```

but this results in a `SIGABRT` with the following error `*** Assertion failure in -[XCTestExpectation fulfill], /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/XCTest_Sim/XCTest-9530/XCTestFramework/Classes/XCTestCase+AsynchronousTesting.m:450`

I've successfully tested the function using `dispatch_groups` and that works. But couldn't figure out why the XCTestExpectation is raising an exception for multiple expectations.

Comment: Any update on this? Even I am facing this crash

Comment: Your method `-(void)syncData:(void (^)(NSString *type, NSError *error))completionBlock`is executing its `completionBlock` more than once (3 times).

Comment: `-waitForExpectationsWithTimeout:` will wait for all the expectations to be fulfilled (3 in this case).